# Problems loading dynamic python module using __init__.py

Tags: python, module, loading, instantiation, init

I'm trying to do an `__init__.py` that load module and instantiate dinamically internal namesake class. With a file tree like

```
 importer/
     __init__.py         # The file i'm writing
     asd.py              # It contains class asd
     bsd.py              # It contains class bsd
```

And `__init__.py` with

```
importername=__name__

def load(modname,paramlist = []):

  if modname in globals():
    print 'Module %s already loaded.' % (modname)
  else:
    imported_mod = __import__(importername + '.' + modname, fromlist = ["*"])
    try:
        globals()[modname]=getattr(imported_mod,modname)(*paramlist)
    except Exception, e:
        print 'Module %s not loaded: %s.' % (modname, e)
```

If I run

```
import importer
importer.load('asd')
print importer.asd.name
'ASD!'
```

It works like a charm, but if I run

```
from importer import *
load('asd')
print asd.name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'asd' is not defined
```

Can I fix it in some way? Thank you.

Comment: Dynamically updating global variables is considered bad practice in Python. What do you actually want this for? There's probably a better way.

Comment: Look at my comment in Ned answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as truly global in Python.  When you use globals() in `importer/__init__.py`, you are accessing the module's namespace.  Your second non-working sample is adding 'asd' to importer, not to your test module.

The best you could is modify importer so you could do:

```
from importer import *
asd = load('asd')
print asd.name
```

But as Thomas K suggests: this is kind of odd, perhaps there's a simpler way to solve your problem?

Comment: I need a sort of set of singleton classes, dynamically loadable, and reachable in every part of the program, like as import statement offer.

Comment: @Emilio: Um, that doesn't make it clearer, at least to me. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: I need a sort of plugin factory, loaded a single time, that have to load and instantiate dinamically plugins in a directory (with .load() and .unload()). The 'import' way is ok because i need to reach this factory from everywhere in the code.

Comment: @Emilio: Can you, for example, store the loaded plugins in a list or a dict? You could even subclass `dict`, so that when you do `asd = plugins['asd']`, it loads the asd plugin if it isn't already loaded. Loading plugins is the easy bit: working out the best way to reference them in your code is what's interesting.

Comment: If i initialize this plugin{} dict in a module moddict.py, i can import it from everywhere calling `import moddict` and using as moddict.plugin['pluginname'].method(). And it's ok, but is it cleaner than my solution?

Comment: @Emilio: I don't know exactly what you're trying to do with the plugins, but that sounds OK to me. It also means you can easily do tests like `if 'asd' in plugins`.

Comment: @Ned: i've a question about your answer. If, as you say, `import * from importer` and `load('asd')` imports asd to module namespace and not to test namespace, there is a way to reach it? I have no `import` module loaded.